# Local SMTP Server — prevent spam flag?

Tags: postfix, sendmail, spam-prevention

I opened up port 25 on my router, so now I can use `sendmail` to send email.

However, the emails I send are being marked as spam by my personal gmail account (understandably). The "from" field defaults to `username@mycomputer.local`, which is of course not a real domain, but only my account on the local network.

Externally, the mail is shown to be sent from my ISP dynamic hostname and external IP.

I looked around on serverfault [[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam) question] which recommended I check blacklists. I checked... and oddly enough, my home IP *is* on two blacklists. I suspect this is not due to my direct actions (I've only recently set up a webserver on my home network, and never used `sendmail` anywhere except my own personal email address), but rather than the blacklists automatically includes residential IPs.

How may I prevent my emails from being sent to spam? I believe this may be a home-network-specific question. And this is not solely Gmail-specific, for I would like emails to be accepted by a variety of email service providers (all my own email, though, so I need not worry about spam reports). Might I need DKIM, SPF, or some other validation system? I would like this to be as simple as possible.

I do own a domain name, however, which forwards to my home IP. Although no mail server exists, could I potentially send mail as `me@example.com`?

Comment: First step would be: Don't use a residential/consumer level internet service.

Comment: Alright, so I'll just forget this project? As a somewhat-hackish alternative, I can just have gmail forward my messages around. Thanks.